# Can't see property of typescript mixins

Tags: typescript, mixins, extends

I can't see (vs code/whisper) `id` of my property when I am using mixins.

My code is:

```
class User {
    // @ts-ignore
    id: number;
} 

function Parent<TBase>(Base: TBase) {
  return class ParentChild {  
    _object: TBase;

    constructor (o: TBase) {
        this._object = o;
    } 

    dump(): void {
        console.log(this._object);
    }
  };
}

class Test extends Parent(User) {

}

const o = {id: 2} as any;
const i = new Test(o);

// problem
console.log(i._object.id);
```

Problem is on `console.log(i._object.id);` line. I am getting an error: `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'typeof User'`.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Base` parameter in `Parent`? The code never uses it.

Comment: Nothing, just mess from my testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By passing `Base` as a parameter, you're using `typeof User` (the constructor function type) as `TBase` rather than `User` (the type of `User` instances). I think you just want `User`, by specifying the generic argument:

```typescript
class User {
    // @ts-ignore
    id: number;
} 

function Parent<TBase>() {
//             ^^^^^^^^^
  return class ParentChild {  
    _object: TBase;

    constructor (o: TBase) {
        this._object = o;
    } 

    dump(): void {
        console.log(this._object);
    }
  };
}

class Test extends Parent<User>() {
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

}

const o = {id: 2} as any;
const i = new Test(o);

// problem
console.log(i._object.id);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoHofQAEAXCAWgEsBzAOwHskFNtyATALmmoFcBbAI2QBudAF9o6dADMu1YEXK1q0AApgG1IgB4AKgCFICAHwAKAJRp0ebNZvQAeg8eOmDIlyRLQkGKvVEAwgAW5CAsaFhMWAD6tHwAVghyHHoGwpHQwIoQREhccvTQxrTJ+ojmGLZYRMEQAHQx8YlE0AC80LTC1mIS1iy8AA5mHAButKwWlRlZtCAItSC0lMbV5HUNCXKmndgiTCLCu+heUNDaCNnQCAAeRAjULD5qd1rwyCbllviTk06-vxKHTLUC60VpoVgcABMYkg0DA1AAnsIgRdyGDqAgAO6nc5EIpbCQomZzBZLcj1WIbIi1VhbIA)

A couple of other notes:

- There's no need for the `as any` on `o`.
- Side note: If you just want the shape of `User` without implementation, use `interface User { id: number; }` instead of `class`. Then you won't need the `@ts-ignore`. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANy4C+yuuMlICYwA9iGQAFOFAjgAPABUAQnEwA+ABQBKHLgD0Gwjt3IAeoaNH8yMWEpRBCADbz0w0eLABhABbAbxHAVMEA+ny0AFYQPOSy8hBMfsgIAuhgUJQ8fFDISnwRcphqeHoEYB7oAHSBIWFgyAC8yHxMOqzsOsQ0AA6q5ABufCTqBXEJfDYQJTZ8AOZKRcCl5aE8Kg2EzKbMTKu4tvbIUhCJyBAAHpAgxA4iYpIY0Mp57JvxIAd8NTgk5ABM61sJVcBvEAQADuu32YEyS3YT3Qw1G4ymwDKQQWYBKJCWQA).

Comment: Thank you @T.J. Crowder! last question. Is there any way how to print (in runtime) object properties from TBase in `ParentChild` constructor? For in this example `id: number`. I know that types/interfaces are not runtime variables.

Comment: The goal is create `_object` with default values based on generic type.

Comment: @yihereg819 - You can get the property names (`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`), but not the TypeScript types, which as you say don't exist at runtime. (In this particular case, `typeof o.id` would give you `"number"`, but that only works for primitives.) If you want to use the values from `o` without doing what you've done (`this._object = o`), you could use `Object.assign` to do a shallow copy: `this._object = Object.assign({}, o);` But I may not be understanding you correctly.